# Setting TextView color to a <selector> programmatically

Tags: android, android-resources

I have the following selector defined in an XML file under *res/color/redeemlist_item_color.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <item android:state_pressed="true"
            android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- pressed -->

      <item android:state_selected="true"
            android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- focused -->

      <item android:color="#000000" /> <!-- default -->

   </selector>
```

I also have a `TextView` in a `ListView` item layout. When I set `android:textColor` on this `TextView` to the above selector in XML, then the color changes correctly when the item is selected. However, I am trying to set this resource programmatically in the following way:

```
holder.label.setTextColor(R.color.redeemlist_item_color);
```

When set in this way, the color no longer changes. Can a selector be assigned to a `TextView` in this way?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I think you might need to add `findViewById` or something of that variety

---

Edit: the above is incorrect as per my comment the proper answer is

```
setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.redeemlist_item_color));
```

Comment: Here is my comment from HD_Mouse:

Ok, maybe I left out too much code. I have already made a call to findViewById(). My problem is not a null pointer exception or anything, the view loads fine. This is code that is in a sub-class of BaseAdapter.

Comment: Let me rephrase it: you need to convert R. into a value. I thought the proper function was getViewbyid. I was wrong... try this: setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redeemlist_item_color));

Comment: @Rasman : This is not correct, one should use **setTextColor ( getResources ().getColorStateList ( R.color.redeemlist_item_color ) );**

Comment: but the getResourse() method didn''t get in the CustomAdapter for a listView

Comment: @Vikky - it sounds like you need to pass the context to your listview adapter and then you can do `android:textColor="@drawable/selector_listview_text"`

Comment: `Resources#getColorStateList(int)` was deprecated in API level 23. Use either `Resources#getColorStateList(int, Theme)` or `ContextCompat.getColorStateList(Context, int)` instead

Answer (score 42):

You have to use [getColorStateList()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColorStateList%28int%29)

I was also struggling with this problem, if you want to have use a `state list`, you need to declare it in the `color` resources folder, instead of the `drawable` folder, and use the `setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.redeemlist_item_color))`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543186/colorstatelist-android-programatically for setting the ColorStateList programmatically.

Comment: `Resources#getColorStateList(int)` was deprecated in API level 23. Use either `Resources#getColorStateList(int, Theme)` or `ContextCompat.getColorStateList(Context, int)` instead

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

holder.label.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.redeemlist_item_color));

instead of :

holder.label.setTextColor(R.color.redeemlist_item_color);

Comment: This is not correct, one should you the **getColorStateList** method and not **getColor**.

Answer (score 1):

```
Can use 

context.getColorStateList(colorSelectorId) // if your app minAPI level >= 23
// or 
ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, colorSelectorId) // for any API


because resources.getColorStateList(id) deprecated: @deprecated Use {@link #getColorStateList(int, Theme)} instead.
```

Example

```
textView.setTextColor(context.getColorStateList(R.color.text_color_selector))
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.text_color_selector))
```

I prefer `ContextCompat.getColorStateList` as it work for all API

Answer (score 0):

Rasman is correct. You need to give the TextView an ID, android:id="@+/something". You retrieve a reference to that particular using that ID and findViewById, and then you may set the text color.

Comment: Ok, maybe I left out too much code. I have already made a call to findViewById(). My problem is not a null pointer exception or anything, the view loads fine. This is code that is in a sub-class of BaseAdapter.