# How to Change the Text Color of Activity Main Drawer in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I am trying to change the text color of the Activity Main Drawer but I cant find where to change it.  I want to change it to a lighter color (white)

[image]

This is whats inside of my activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_city1" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mapmode"
        android:title="Label1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_city2" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass"
        android:title="Label2" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_city3" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces"
        android:title="Label3" />
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_city4" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_input_get"
        android:title="Label4" />
</group>

<item android:title="Account">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_profile" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:title="Profile" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_settings" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Settings" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

I tried inserting android:textColor everywhere but its not working.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:textColor="#FFFFFF">
    <item android:id="@+id/nav_cities" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mapmode"
        android:title="Cities" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Comment: show your color xml if you have..and listitem of drawer xml

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android

Comment: @TwoThumbSticks are you using **NavigationView** provided in android design support library to implement navigation drawer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to initialize the colors you want to use using the
  ColorStateList object.
- After setting up the colors for each state you set the navitaionView
  itemTextColor (navigation.setItemTextColor(yourCustomColorStateList);

[This is where I got the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042794/changing-text-color-of-menu-item-in-navigation-drawer)
[Here is another related Stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543186/colorstatelist-android-programatically/17788095#17788095)
[Official Android documentation of all the available kind of    state](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#state_above_anchor)

example:
Use this inside your onCreate method of your main class

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    /**
     * start of code configuration for color of text of your Navigation Drawer / Menu based on state
     */
    int[][] state = new int[][] {
            new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
            new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
            new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed

    };

    int[] color = new int[] {
            Color.WHITE,
            Color.WHITE,
            Color.WHITE,
            Color.WHITE
    };

    ColorStateList colorStateList1 = new ColorStateList(state, color);


    // FOR NAVIGATION VIEW ITEM ICON COLOR
    int[][] states = new int[][] {
            new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
            new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
            new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed

    };

    int[] colors = new int[] {
            Color.WHITE,
            Color.WHITE,
            Color.WHITE,
            Color.WHITE
    };
    ColorStateList colorStateList2 = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    navigationView.setItemTextColor(colorStateList1);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(colorStateList2);
    /**
     * end of code configuration for color of text of your Navigation Drawer / Menu based on state
     */
```

Comment: Well explained and code works like a charm thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve same through xml by just using `app:itemTextColor` inside your NavigationView:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite">
```

Adding the above single line to your xml should work in your case.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your using the new `Android Support Design Library`. I haven't used it. 
I feel you need to have a some **Header Layout** which consists of the `TextView` as shown in the above screenshot.
And later in the Java code you can access the Header Layout and using `findViewById()` to get the `TextView`s.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can using **app:itemTextColor** inside **your NavigationVi**ew

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFDFE3"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        <!-- here you can change color of items like this. -->
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorHeaderBackground"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```