# How do I change Item title font color for an Item that contains a menu in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I've been searching for a way to change a specific font color in my nav drawer.  I can change the font colors for other item titles but not ones containing a menu.

```
<group
    android:id="something"
    android:checkableBehavior="single>
    <item
        android:title="Menu Heading>   <--This is what I want to change-->
        <menu>
            <item android:title="stuff"/> <--This i can change-->
            <item android:title="stuff"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</group>
```

I can change all other title colors with app:itemTextColor in the main activity.  I've tried changing my theme's alternate font color.  I'm still relatively new to programming in general, so I'm assuming I'm missing something.  The only thing i can think of is to use action layout and just inflate a custom layout in the items, but I'd prefer to not redo all of my onClicks.  As it is my designer wants dark menu and the text is defaulted to black regardless of theme changes so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing text color of menu item in navigation drawer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042794/changing-text-color-of-menu-item-in-navigation-drawer)

Comment: 100% duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216457/navigation-drawer-menu-item-title-color-in-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the menu title instead of the individual item titles I just used html tags in the strings resource for color The title and referenced the strings xml as the title.  This can be done for doing individual colors for each item also.

```
<string name="testTitle"><font color="#303F9F">The title</font></string>

<group
android:id="something"
android:checkableBehavior="single>
<item
    android:title="@string/testTitle">   <--This is what I want to change-->
    <menu>
        <item android:title="stuff"/> <--This i can change-->
        <item android:title="stuff"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

I also noticed that this doesn't work if you have secondary text color in set in your styles.

Answer (score 3):

Using **app:itemTextColor**, the menu item title color can be set. You can refer following xml code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/your_menuitem_icon_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/your_menuitem_title_color"
    app:menu="@menu/menu" />
```

Comment: I've done that to get the text color for my menu items but the header for each menu is black and i cant find where to change that part.

Comment: set custom theme to your activity and in that theme, put this textColorSecondary item <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>