# How to change the item color of androids navigation drawer if the item is the currently selected one?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have the following problem: I have a DrawerLayout with a NavigationView to create a navigation drawer. Now i want to change the text color of the item when it is the currently selected one. It is a dark purple by default and i want to change it to my accent color.

I tried setting `app:textAppearance="@style/customStyle"` and then it does not change the textColor anymore if a item is the selected one. But i just can´t find out which attribute i have to set in `customStyle` to achieve a change of the textColor.

I tried every attribute starting with `android:textColor...` like `android:textColorHighlight` and so on.
I also tried changing the background to a state selector but as expected this only changes the background of the item when it is selected.

I can´t believe that such a simple thing is driving me crazy like that so every help is appreciated. Thanks :D

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132260/how-do-i-change-item-title-font-color-for-an-item-that-contains-a-menu-in-naviga/38132450#38132450

Comment: thank you! this solved my problem just needed to set app:itemTextColor to my selector.