# How can I change the icon of the navigation drawer and its item android studio

Tags: java, android

im new on android studio and I use the navigation drawer for my app. but I don't know how to change the icon of each on navigation drawer by default. I want to use my own icon PLEASE HELP!

This I want to change the icon:

[image]

and also of this item

[image]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemIconTint="#000000"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Post nav_header_main.xml & activity_main_drawer.xml from menu also

Comment: Refer this for 2nd image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132260/how-do-i-change-item-title-font-color-for-an-item-that-contains-a-menu-in-naviga/38132450#38132450

Comment: Jerome Lim, I would recommend to place the image directly on the post. This link might break and would not be there in future.

Comment: Change your icons in `activity_main_drawer.xml` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)create a menu folder in R folder

2)now in menu create navigation_menu.xml file : 
paste this code - add icons from drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:title="Home"
            android:icon="@drawable/user"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/earn"
            android:title="Wallet"
            android:icon="@drawable/earn"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/notifications"
            android:title="Notifications"
            android:icon="@drawable/notification"
            />
    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:menuCategory="secondary"
        android:id="@+id/secondary">
        <item
            android:title="Help"
            android:visible="false"
            android:id="@+id/help"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
            />
        <item
            android:title="About Us"
            android:id="@+id/aboutus"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_name"
            >
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

add this menu file in NavigaitonView tag

3)if you want to create your own toolbar for Navigation view.
create toolbar.xml in your layout folder and paste this code
** add image in ImageView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_hamburger"
        android:id="@+id/hamburger"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/title_text"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

4)add this toolbar in layout file

```
  <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

5) goto Activity where you want to create Navigation View and do the following

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {


    TextView titleToolbarTV;
    ImageView  hamburgerIV;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        titleToolbarTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_text); 

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        hamburgerIV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hamburger);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.base_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        loginPreferences = new LoginPreferences(MainActivity.this);
        user = loginPreferences.getUser();
        hamburgerIV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
                else{
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });

 }
 }
```

***dont forget to add NoActionBar for your layout file

Comment: where should i put NoActionBar?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use toolbar and set navigation icon for it.

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view_main_activity);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_menu);
```

Comment: note that you must use NoActionBar theme for your activity to support toolbar.

Comment: where should i put noaction bar?

Comment: you include app_bar_main in your DrawerLayout, in this file you should have a toolbar for activity that has this layout. you should setSupportActionBar(toolbar) and after that use above code.

Comment: toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Answer (score 0):

When I created a navigation view using default template provided by android studio, I faced same problem. I wanted to change the background of the navigation view header and place my own icon.

But I used simple technique to go step wise down to the header of navigation drawer. Please check this line from your code under NavigationView

```
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
```

This is the navigation header layout under folder **layout**. Open this file and place code here. My header looks like this, I have assigned the nice black background (with gradient) to this.

**To assign** my own application icon, I have provided my own drawable (or mipmap) under the image view. Notice this ImageView has been placed by the default template. **P.S** this is trimmed code of my navigation header, do not want to overwhelm you with unnecessary code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar">

   <!--My app icon-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <!--My company/product name-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@string/IDS_0235"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextLight"/>

    <!--My website link-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```