# How to set layout background tint from string programmatically?

Tags: android, layout, colors, hex, android-linearlayout

I tried this code:

```
LinearLayout someLayout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.someLayout);
        someLayout.setBackgroundTintList(context.getResources().getColorStateList(Color.parseColor("#ff8800")));
```

But I'm getting an error: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`
I'm getting the color hex from external source so I can't embed it in colors.xml.
Also I want to change the tint, not the background so setBackground is not an option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create ColorStateList programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543186/how-do-i-create-colorstatelist-programmatically)

Comment: "Possible duplicate"  means "if you know how to do this then you know how to solve your problem"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I figured I can't use getColorStateList() so I searched for another way to do it.
At the end I was able to set color tint using the following code:

```
LinearLayout someLayout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.someLayout);
        someLayout.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff8800"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

This worked as if I changed the backgroundTint property in the xml file, so it's perfect for my problem.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to manage using the following line. change it to your circumstances.

```
myView.getBackground().setTint(currentView.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

Answer (score 2):

For Kotlin ,
I modified @Krestek answer :

```
someLayout.background.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff8800"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using `BindingAdapter`, `Kotlin` and targeting more recent Android versions:

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("app:backgroundTint")
fun LinearLayout.setBackgroundTint(@ColorInt color: Int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        background.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(color, BlendMode.SRC_ATOP)
    } else {
        background.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this like that because getColorStateList method expect int id of resource, and you are passing RGB color int. You should create color state list following this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

and then set it like this:

```
.getColorStateList(R.color.your_xml_name)
```

Comment: Yeah I figured, so I used other method.